# Atomic commits best practice

Tags: git

I am using git to manage a project. Usually I work on a feature during a week and do very small commits like:

- Implement a stub for some entity class;
- Add repository service for the entity;
- Add test for entity saving;
- Implement UI for the entities list;
- ...

Each of these commits are very small (~20-50 lines) but they depend from each other. And each commit keeps the whole system working for sure.

As an opposite approach I could create a single commit for ~500+ lines "Implement feature X".

**The question is** what is the best practice? Which approach commits are atomic?

PS. *I know how to squash commits. What I am asking is the PHILOSOPHY part.*

Comment: You can do small commits in side branch, than you can make not fast forward merge to introduce "Implement feature X" commit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You exemplified with 4 commits that sound totally reasonable to be different commits even though they are all related to the same task.

Smaller commits are always better than longer ones. But you could question "How small"? I would use the following philosophy:

> If you can describe what you did in this commit in a short sentence
>   and it makes sense, commit.

Comment: In addition, if you cannot describe your commit on a simple sentence, it should probably be split into several commits

Answer (score 1):

Small commits is the best practice. You can more easily see which change introduced a bug. It's easier to work with a team where you need to merge your work together.

This is independent of which revision control system you use.

EDIT:

Another benefit is that as you build and commit your software incrementally, you can fearlessly try something on the next step, knowing that when something doesn't work it's a quick reset to get back to the last step where everything so far was working.

Answer (score 0):

As much as you can, try having a given commit represent "one logical unit of work".  This makes it easier to understand the git history.

Comment: I am trying to avoid commits like "Implement a new version with all features". But I agreed, the big commits make commits history clearer. The question is how to define the border and which way is better. That's why I am asking,